# Is there a purely functional immutable Map implementation for Java?

Tags: java, functional-programming

I have a Map in Java containing a number of key/value pairs.

I want to create a version of this Map with additional key/value pairs, but without losing the old version.

The simple solution would be to copy the old Map, and then add the additional key/value pairs, but I understand that there are immutable Map algorithms that can achieve this more efficiently.

Can anyone point me to such an implementation usable in vanilla Java (ie. not a Clojure or Scala library)?

Comment: I don't see how it would be possible to build an immutable map from a mutable one, without copying the entries from the mutable map to the immutable one.

Comment: You can create a modified copy of a Map rather like Properties wraps other properties files.  This only works well in very specific cases where you have a small number of modifications of a very large map.

Comment: Doesn't look like it, in the standard packaging; there is a [copy-on-write-_ArrayList_](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).  You can probably find the implementation for that somewhere online...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collections library at https://pcollections.org/ appears to provide efficient persistent collection implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just invoke Map.putAll(Map other)? I would assume the JVM implements this efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You could use java.util.Properties, using the default-values feature.